# I want to use a scope variable as part of my javascript's onfocus function's argument

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<input ng-show="showFolderNameInput" 
       type="text" 
       name="folderName" 
       ng-model="folderName" 
       style="margin-left: 5%; width: 90%;padding-left:5px;" 
       placeholder="{{enterFolderName}}" 
       autofocus/>
```

Here is some HTML, I want to add a javascript handler `onfocus=setSelectionRange(aaa,bbb)`, and I want its arguments "aaa" and "bbb" to be a scope variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think in a more "angularjs" way:

simply use [`ng-focus`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus):

```
<input ng-show="showFolderNameInput" 
   type="text" 
   name="folderName" 
   ng-model="folderName" 
   style="margin-left: 5%; width: 90%;padding-left:5px;" 
   placeholder="{{enterFolderName}}" 
   autofocus
   ng-focus="focused(aaa,bbb)"/>
```

and in your controller, create the listener:

```
$scope.focused = function(aaa, bbb){
  console.log(aaa, bbb);
}
```

This way, you'll be able to handle all your javascript in your controller: this will let you to have a more organized and maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

**use ng-focus**

```
<input ng-show="showFolderNameInput" type="text" name="folderName" ng-model="folderName" style="margin-left: 5%; width: 90%;padding-left:5px;" placeholder="{{enterFolderName}}" ng-focus=setSelectionRange(aaa,bbb)/>
```